# How to show sliding menu & fragment of selected option In same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sliding

```
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array

    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("\nFirst Year", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("\nSecond Year", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("\nThird Year", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        fragment = new FirstYear();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecondYear();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ThirdYear();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

1. I want to show slider menu & fragment of clicked in the menu in same activity.for ex: I   click first option(first year) of slider menu it shows right side first year fragment.
   2.Can I adjust width of slider menu. for showing more space for fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code from Android Hive, [Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/), by Ravi Tamada:

> NavDrawerItem.java
>
> ```
> public class NavDrawerItem {
>
>     private String title;
>     private int icon;
>     private String count = "0";
>     // boolean to set visiblity of the counter
>     private boolean isCounterVisible = false;
>
>     public NavDrawerItem(){}
>
>     public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon){
>         this.title = title;
>         this.icon = icon;
>     }
>
>     public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon, boolean isCounterVisible, String count){
>         this.title = title;
>         this.icon = icon;
>         this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
>         this.count = count;
>     }
>
>     public String getTitle(){
>         return this.title;
>     }
>
>     public int getIcon(){
>         return this.icon;
>     }
>
>     public String getCount(){
>         return this.count;
>     }
>
>     public boolean getCounterVisibility(){
>         return this.isCounterVisible;
>     }
>
>     public void setTitle(String title){
>         this.title = title;
>     }
>
>     public void setIcon(int icon){
>         this.icon = icon;
>     }
>
>     public void setCount(String count){
>         this.count = count;
>     }
>
>     public void setCounterVisibility(boolean isCounterVisible){
>         this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> NavDrawerListAdapter.java
>
> ```
> import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;
> import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
> import android.widget.ImageView;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>
>     private Context context;
>     private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
>
>     public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
>         this.context = context;
>         this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public int getCount() {
>         return navDrawerItems.size();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public Object getItem(int position) {       
>         return navDrawerItems.get(position);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public long getItemId(int position) {
>         return position;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>         if (convertView == null) {
>             LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
>                     context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
>         }
>
>         ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
>         TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
>         TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
>
>         imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());     
>
>         txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
>
>         // displaying count
>         // check whether it set visible or not
>         if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
>             txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
>         }else{
>             // hide the counter view
>             txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>         }
>
>         return convertView;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> MainActivity.java
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
>     private ListView mDrawerList;
>     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
>
>     // nav drawer title
>     private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
>
>     // used to store app title
>     private CharSequence mTitle;
>
>     // slide menu items
>     private String[] navMenuTitles;
>     private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
>
>     private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
>     private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
>
>         // load slide menu items
>         navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
>
>         // nav drawer icons from resources
>         navMenuIcons = getResources()
>                 .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
>
>         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
>
>         navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
>
>         // adding nav drawer items to array
>         // Home
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
>         // Find People
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
>         // Photos
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
>         // Communities, Will add a counter here
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
>         // Pages
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
>         // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
>
>
>         // Recycle the typed array
>         navMenuIcons.recycle();
>
>         // setting the nav drawer list adapter
>         adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
>                 navDrawerItems);
>         mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>         // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
>         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
>         getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
>
>         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
>                 R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
>                 R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
>                 R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
>         ){
>             public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
>                 getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
>                 // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
>                 invalidateOptionsMenu();
>             }
>
>             public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
>                 getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
>                 // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
>                 invalidateOptionsMenu();
>             }
>         };
>         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
>
>         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>             // on first time display view for first nav item
>             displayView(0);
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>         // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
>         if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
>             return true;
>         }
>         // Handle action bar actions click
>         switch (item.getItemId()) {
>         case R.id.action_settings:
>             return true;
>         default:
>             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>         }
>     }
>
>     /***
>      * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
>      */
>     @Override
>     public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>         // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
>         boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
>         menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
>         return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
>         mTitle = title;
>         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
>      * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
>      */
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
>         mDrawerToggle.syncState();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
>         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
>         // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
>         mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
>     }
> ```
>
> HomeFragment.java
>
> ```
> package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;
>
> import android.app.Fragment;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
>
> public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
>
>     public HomeFragment(){}
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
>
>         return rootView;
>     }
> }
> ```